# Change a particular node in branch that each users have in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I update a particular node that all users have in their own branch?

I am trying to update a users set of points back to 15 after a certain amount of days by a push of a button. I know how to update 1 users node but can't seem to figure out how to do create a function that when I push a button it resets all users that have that branch/var back to 15.

Otherwise, I would have to do it individually which is obviously not efficient.

This is my code to reset 1 of the student's node by a click of a button

```
Database.database().reference().root.child("students").child(userId).updateChildValues(["points": self.newPoints])
```

How do I write a method to reset all students who have the value "points" key by a press of a button?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't use **wildcards** to replace `userId` and therefore apply it to every node. You would probably need to fetch the entire `students` node, and update them one by one using a *for* loop,  which would be very inefficient.

You probably want to use a different data structure in your database that would be more appropriate to your situation. Thats said, if you still want to stick with your current structure you can try having your client update a single *boolean* flag in your database, and then program a trigger function in *node.js* so that the update is handled on the server side directly. Check out : [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

Comment: thanks for the insight, I was thinking of a for loop, however, what would that look like? with the root of the branch being "students" followed by "studentUserId" and then in this path there is a key called "points". Cycle through each of the student's value of "points" than update these individual values how? Hope this makes sense, your concept of trigger function in node.js i will check out, however I am still a rookie at this so it already seems to far fetched for me now but wil try.

Comment: would it work if I create a structured tree node where I call the base "studentsPoints" and then use the UserId as if it were autoIds. From there I can store the points value in there and then if I have a new user I just at the userId to the current studentsPoints node with there points value. So its data structure is flat and not nested. However, need to know if there is a function to change all nodes from that one studentsPoints node to 15points, and it will cycle through all userIds and change it to 15. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I don't quite get the data structure that you are suggesting. If you would do it on the client side again you would fetch the parent node ```students```, cast the result as a _NSDictionnary_, go through it using a ```for ... in``` loop to retrieve all existing keys (here _userIds_), and using each of them to perform an update of their subnode _points_. Again this would be very inefficient. Such an operation should be done on the server side and only triggered by the client. For this, you should use Firebase Cloud Functions. Your client app should always remain as light as possible.

Comment: Besides, I do not believe that such a function, that would update all subnodes at once, exists in the Firebase API.

Comment: Hi vbuzze, yes I am looking for a function that updates all subnodes from the students parent node. Do you know of one? Saves me filtering through all nodes.

Comment: cause if there is a function that updates all subnodes I will restructer my data tree. So i can just call that function when i need to reset all nodes at once under that parent node of students.